# Stop Object.keys from iterating over custom global methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have added a method to the ***typescript*** array type that I usually use in the code like e.g.:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        extend(other_array : T[]) : void;
    } }

Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array : Array<any>) {
    other_array.forEach(function(v) {this.push(v)}, this);    
}
```

However, elsewhere in the code I have an array of 6 elements that I wish to loop through, but the extended method is returned with the elements, e.g.:

```
for(let i in Object.keys(days)) {
      let d = days[i];

}
```

I have also tried getOwnPropertyNames, which results in the same issue.

How can I loop only over the six elements in *typescript* ?

Comment: Why not just use `for (let d of days)`?

Comment: There's no reason to use `Object.keys` here. You can use regular `for` loop: `for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) { ... } ` Or `for ... of` as suggested above

Comment: In the end I did for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) { ... } as I needed the index as well. I was curious about the keys thing more than anything. Thanks

Comment: The problem itself is that `Object.keys` returns an *array* - You then use `for (let i in keysArray)`, which will show all enumerable properties up-through the prototype chain for this array.

Comment: It is so wrong to lookup an array's `keys()` to iterate over its elements. Why would you do that? Also, why would you modify built in object prototypes? You should fix both issues I mentioned (which are known to be problematic), then you won't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`for of`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/for...of.html)

```
for(let d of days) {
  // d  is defined here
}
```

`For of` just emits a for loop so it avoids using `Object.keys()`

If you really want to use `Object.keys`, you need to modify `Array.prototype` marking that property as not enumerable.

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'extend', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function (other_array: Array < any > ) {
    other_array.forEach(function(v) {
      this.push(v)
    }, this);
  }
});
```

Or even better, stop using your custom extend and just use push with spread

Instead of

```
 myArray.extend(arr);
```

You can do

```
 myArray.push(...arr)
```